# jquery change url include part of the li's class

Tags: jquery, url

I got some list has links like:

```
<li class="folder340 collapsable"><a href="http://www.domain.com/title01" class="">   <span>Title01</span></a></li>
<li class="folder360 collapsable"><a href="http://www.domain.com/title02" class=""><span>Title02</span></a></li>
```

I want them become to:

```
<li class="folder340 collapsable"><a href="http://www.domain.com/340" class="">   <span>Title01</span></a></li>
<li class="folder360 collapsable"><a href="http://www.domain.com/360" class=""><span>Title02</span></a></li>
```

I know I should use something like:

```
    var url = $(this).find('a').attr('href') + "this need to be the li class and minus the text folder";
```

Any idea?

Comment: are these <li> classes already set and there's no changing the structure of the <li>  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('.collapsable').each(function(){
    //Select some elements
    var $li = $(this);
    var $link = $li.find("a");

    //Grab the number from the class name beginning with 'folder'
    var folderNum = /folder([\d]+)/g.exec($li.attr("class"))[1];

    //Get the text from the span, this will be what we need to replace in the url 
    var titleToReplace = $link.find("span").text().toLowerCase();

    //Get the original URL
    var originalUrl = $link.attr('href');

    //Replace the part of the URL
    var newUrl = originalUrl.replace(titleToReplace, folderNum);

    $link.attr("href", newUrl);
});
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/q4XJs/

Answer (score 1):

Var className = $(".collapsible").attr("class");

Then you can just remove the text "folder" using simple JavaScript string functions..

Then just store the final domain in a variable and just set it using $("specefic-collapsible").attr("href") = finalURL;

Sorry if my answer is not formatted correctly, but I am on my mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {
        $('li.collapsable').each(function()
        {
            //console.log($(this).attr('class'));
            var cls  = $(this).attr('class').replace('folder',"").replace(" collapsable","");
            var link = $(this).find('a');
            link.attr('href',"http://www.domain.com/"+cls)
            console.log(cls);
        });
    });

</script>
<ul>
    <li class="folder340 collapsable"><a href="http://www.domain.com/title01" class="">   <span>Title01</span></a></li>
    <li class="folder360 collapsable"><a href="http://www.domain.com/title02" class=""><span>Title02</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$('li a').each(function(){
    var cls = $(this).parent().attr('class').split(' ')[0];

    var folder = cls.split('folder')[1];

$(this).attr('href', 'http://www.domain.com/'+folder);
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nD4qL/

Comment: Be aware that this is a bit fragile.  It requires there be two classes on each li and the first class to be the folder to use.  Chris Barrs solution is much less fragile.

Comment: Hi just a quick one if I want to keep the original url just add the folder number at the end like:

<li class="folder340 collapsable"><a href="http://www.domain.com/title01/340" class="">   <span>Title01</span></a></li>
    <li class="folder360 collapsable"><a href="http://www.domain.com/title02/360" class=""><span>Title02</span></a></li>

Thanks

Comment: Then you want to store the original href and reuse it. 

var href = $(this).attr('href');

Then do $(this).attr('href', href+folder);

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/jdCVq/

JS:-

```
$(function(){
    $(".collapsable").each(function(){
        var oldhref=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
        var className = $(this).attr("class");
        className=className.replace("folder","").replace(" collapsable","");
        oldhref=oldhref.replace($(this).find("a").text().toLowerCase().trim(),className);
        $(this).find("a").attr("href",oldhref);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('li').each(function(){
    var n=$(this).attr('class').split(" ")[0].length;
     var x=$(this).attr('class').substring(n-3,n);
     $(this).find('a').attr('href','http://www.domain.com/'+x);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<li class="folder340 collapsable"><a id="link1" href="http://www.domain.com/title01" class="">   <span>Title01</span></a></li>
<li class="folder360 collapsable"><a id="link2" href="http://www.domain.com/title02" class=""><span>Title02</span></a></li>
```

JS:

```
$("#link1").attr("href", "http://www.domain.com/340");

$("#link2").attr("href", "http://www.domain.com/360");
```

Comment: This will not be very reusable at all.  What if there are 100 links?

Comment: Loop over what? You manually added ID's and manually set each URL.

Comment: loop to add id and change link

Comment: anyway, people love to split things, then get back together